# Convert Column Names to Rows in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a table in Hive. I have to convert the the column names to rows. The table that I have is as follows -

`+---------+---------+---------+
|Table 1  | Table 2 | Table 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|    A    |    D    |    F    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|    B    |    E    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
|    C    |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+`

I need to convert it to a table with 2 columns. The first column will have the header -> Table name and values in the first column will be the column names of the old table. The final output should look like this -

```
+-----------+--------+
|Table Name |   Val  |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 1  |    A   |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 1  |    B   |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 1  |    C   |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 2  |    D   |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 2  |    E   |
+-----------+--------+
|  Table 3  |    F   |
+-----------+--------+
```

I am stuck. How do I get the needed output using Hive ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`, provide static values for 1st column corresponding your column names:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as
select * from 
(
select 'Table 1' as Table_Name, Table_1 as Val from your_table
UNION ALL
select 'Table 2' as Table_Name, Table_2 as Val from your_table
UNION ALL
select 'Table 3' as Table_Name, Table_3 as Val from your_table
) s where Val is not NULL
;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. But we will have to hard code the column names and values in this case. what if the number of values is too high? Is there a way in which we can derive the values rather than hard coding them?

Comment: Hive itself does not support dynamic SQL unfortunately. You can try to generate this SQL extracting columns from DESCRIBE command output using shell